# Postgresql slow array assignment

Tags: arrays, performance, postgresql, function, stored-procedures

I am working on a stored procedure / function in postgresql. I have a table called sports, and I have an array of sports%ROWTYPE:

```
records = "sports"[10000];
```

I also have a loop (10 000 iterations), where I create a record and assign it to the records array:

```
for idx in ....
loop
   record.x = something;
   record.y = something_else

   records[idx] = record;
end loop;
```

For some reason, the statement `records[idx] = record;` takes more than 20 seconds to get executed (for the 10 000 iterations).

I don't know why this assignment is taking so long.

**Edit**

I have a stored procedure with 3 parameters

```
x text;
y integer[][];
z integer[];
```

My goal is to store these data in a table like below:

```
x | y[0]  | z[0]
x | y[1]  | z[1]
x | y[..] | z[..]
x | y[n]  | z[n]
```

Comment: I also tried: `records =  array_append(records, record);` but it takes around 15 seconds

Comment: Why are you creating an array rather than a temporary table? PostgreSQL is a dbms, not an "ams". It is likely that things will be much faster if you store your data in a temp table than in an array. PostgreSQL even has native support for transaction-local temporary tables, so it is ridiculously easy to store this in a table. Finally, your explanation smells of an XY problem. Please explain what you are trying to achieve; it is much more likely you'll get a satisfactory answer that way.

Comment: I added some more information

Comment: If you can, try your code with PG 9.5 alpha and measure the difference. Your case looks like what [commit 1dc5ebc9](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=1dc5ebc9077ab742) is meant to address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't generally modify arrays in-place. When you modify one it gets copied to make the new one.

You should avoid trying to iteratively build or modify arrays. Instead use sets. In this case I would define a function to build one record, and I'd call it with `array_agg` to create the array, like

```
select array_agg(r)
from generate_series(1,10000) i,
     my_function(whatever_input_you_need)
into records;
```

Even better if you can get away without defining the function by using a `ROW(...)` constructor, like:

```
select array_agg(ROW(col1, col2, col3))
from generate_series(1,10000) i,
     my_function(whatever_input_you_need);
```

Daniel Vérté [noted that this has changed for arrays modified in plpgsql in PostgreSQL 9.5](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=1dc5ebc9077ab742), so it should be more efficient. On 9.5 your code might perform OK, and it'd be interesting to see the difference.

Comment: I actually tried that solution. It went down to 4 secondes. It's much better but I need something faster. I'll give the ROW solution a go

Comment: @benjamin.d The less you have to split into separate functions the better. Ideal would be to do it in one query.